# How do I unit test for EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocunit

I know how to resolve EXC_BAD_ACCESS issues, but I'm not sure how to unit test for it.  Is there a way to capture EXC_BAD_ACCESS in code instead of simply crashing?

Here's why I ask: I have written a library that heavily uses blocks, like this:

```
- (void)doSomething:(void (^)())myBlock;
```

In my implementation of `doSomething:` I'm going to eventually run the block, like this:

```
myBlock();
```

If a caller passes nil for the block, then it will crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, so the solution is to check that the block exists, like this:

```
if (myBlock) {
    myBlock();
}
```

This nil check is pretty easy to forget, so I'd like a way to write a unit test that fails when the crash occurs.  I suppose a crash could be considered a test failure, but I think it would be nicer for others trying to run the tests to see a nice failure message rather than a crash.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll need to run the test in a subprocess; then you can let the subprocess crash, check for that crash, and fail the test neatly if it occurs.

Working from [Peter Hosey's singleton test code](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/singleton/src/a54e4a35412e/TestSingleton.m).

```
- (void) runTestInSubprocess:(SEL)testCmd {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        // The return value of fork is 0 in the child process, and it is
        // the id of the child process in the parent process.
        if (pid == 0) {
            // Child process: run test
            // isInSubprocess is an ivar of your test case class
            isInSubprocess = YES;
            [self performSelector:testCmd];
            exit(0);
        } else {
            // Parent process: wait for child process to end, check 
            // its status
            int status;
            waitpid(pid, &status, /*options*/ 0);
            // This was a crash; fail the test
            STAssertFalse(WIFSIGNALED(status), @"Test %@ crashed due to signal %d", NSStringFromSelector(testCmd), WTERMSIG(status));
        }
}
```

Each test will then run itself in a subprocess like so:

```
- (void) testSomething {
    if (!isInSubprocess) {
            // Hand off this test's selector to be run in a subprocess
            [self runTestInSubprocess:_cmd];
            return;
    }

    // Put actual test code here
    STAssertEquals(1, 1, @"Something wrong with the universe.");

}
```

You may need to tweak this; I haven't tested it.

Comment: This is very interesting. At first attempt, it ends up failing the test no matter what I do, but the project is targeted as a Cocoa Touch static library, and running the tests launches the iPhone Simulator.  I don't think fork() is going to work there, so I'm going to try this out as a Mac / Cocoa target as well and see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: Ooh, yeah, I don't know if `fork()` is even available on iOS, sorry. I'm having trouble getting this to work completely right, too; I'll update if I figure anything out.

Comment: @greenisus Did you get a chance to work this out successfully on iOS? I'm also looking for a way to make a test fail when a crash occurs, especially in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using one of the assertion macros found in the [Assertions and Logging Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Assertions/Assertions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000014i)

So you could do something like:

```
NSAssert(myBlock != nil, @"myBlock must not be nil")
```

This enforces the preconditions that must be met before the method continues executing.  It also allows the app to crash and will give you a reason why other than EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: This doesn't really help with the unit testing; greenisus could equally well include the `if(myBlock){ myBlock() };` check that he mentioned in the question. The problem, unless I've completely misunderstood, is how to write a unit test that catches _forgetting_ to check the block in the code under test.

Comment: Josh is right.  I could very well use that assertion, but what I'm really trying to test is that my methods don't crash when I pass them a nil block, so that it doesn't matter whether or not myBlock is nil.

Comment: By using the assertion, you are guaranteeing that `myBlock` is not nil.  If you were to test that method with a unit test, the test would fail due to the assertion failing.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.  I want nil to be an acceptable value for myBlock, so I'm looking for a test that makes sure passing nil doesn't cause a crash.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't realize that.